# Error trying to obtain Google Bigquery Storage Client object with OAuth type: SERVICE_ACCOUNT, error

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery

While executing query on Bigquery using JDBC I am getting following exception:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](1000017) Error trying to obtain Google Bigquery Storage Client object with OAuth type: SERVICE_ACCOUNT, error: {1}.
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.createBigQueryStorageClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.serviceAccountOAuth(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.core.BQConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
Caused by: com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba][BigQueryJDBCDriver](1000017) Error trying to obtain Google Bigquery Storage Client object with OAuth type: SERVICE_ACCOUNT, error: {1}.
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getTransportChannel() called when needsExecutor() is true
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.getTransportChannel(InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider.java:204)
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ClientContext.create(ClientContext.java:205)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.stub.EnhancedBigQueryReadStub.create(EnhancedBigQueryReadStub.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryReadClient.<init>(BigQueryReadClient.java:129)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryReadClient.create(BigQueryReadClient.java:110)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.createBigQueryStorageClient(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.client.BQClient.serviceAccountOAuth(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.googlebigquery.core.BQConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.BaseConnectionFactory.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at com.simba.googlebigquery.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
```

I followed this documentation https://www.magnitude.com/drivers/bigquery-odbc-jdbc

Comment: Looks like a service account do not have access to the resource or is missing in the code. In order to debug you should check your credentials running a small test like [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/service-account-file#java). After checking credentials, check overall code with bigquery-odbc-jdbc driver. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Betjens I checked the credentials and it seems to be fine.  Ran example test that you referred in the above comment and it is also working fine but now with JDBC

Comment: Have you also configured your bigquery credentials on simba jdbc? see [link](http://simba.wpengine.com/products/BigQuery/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/bq/authenticating/serviceaccount.htm)

Comment: Yes i have configured the credentials properly. Also to verify if the credentials have proper permission i have used them in bigquery java client and they were working properly. But they are not working with JDBC, i am not sure if that is a credentials issue

Comment: What is the version of the driver you are using?

Comment: I am using driver version 1.2.19.1023 downloaded this archive SimbaJDBCDriverforGoogleBigQuery42_1.2.19.1023.zip and added it to the classpath

Comment: Ok, it looks like this is an ongoing issue. You can check this [thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/206859707), -you will need a google account- and wait for updates.

Comment: So the workaround could be to use older version of driver?

Comment: Indeed, its a matter of testing the scenario with older versions. You can also add additional details to the thread provided.

Comment: Ok thanks @Betjens